# Fill whole new column with the same value based on condition of another column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two different dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  colA = c("pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "sub"),
  colB = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
  colC = ""
)

# Output
  colA colB colC
1 pass    0     
2 pass    0     
3 pass    0     
4 pass    0     
5 sub     1     



df2 <- data.frame(
  colA = c("pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass"),
  colB = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  colC = ""
)

# Output
  colA colB colC
1 pass    0     
2 pass    0     
3 pass    0     
4 pass    0     
5 pass    0
```

What I would like to do now is fill `colC` with only 1's, if a "sub" is present in `colA` (thus indicated by a 1 in `colB`), and with 0's otherwise.

With the code I wrote, I only retrieve `FALSE` as output (in both dataframes).

```
## DF1
df1$colC <- ifelse(df1$colB == 1, rep(df1$colC == 1), rep(df1$colC == 0))


## DF2
df2$colC <- ifelse(df2$colB == 1, rep(df2$colC == 1), rep(df2$colC == 0))
```

The final output should look like this:

## Final output

```
## DF1
  colA colB colC
1 pass    0    1
2 pass    0    1
3 pass    0    1
4 pass    0    1
5 sub     1    1

## DF2
  colA colB colC
1 pass    0    0
2 pass    0    0
3 pass    0    0
4 pass    0    0
5 pass    0    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `%in%` operator with `case_when`

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(colC = case_when("sub" %in% colA ~ 1,
                          TRUE ~ 0))
```

Output:

```
df1
  colA colB colC
1 pass    0    1
2 pass    0    1
3 pass    0    1
4 pass    0    1
5  sub    1    1

df2
  colA colB colC
1 pass    0    0
2 pass    0    0
3 pass    0    0
4 pass    0    0
5 pass    1    0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option...

```
df1$colC <- 1 * any(df1$colA == "sub")  #the 1* forces conversion to integer
```

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```r
df1$colC <- ifelse(max(df1$colA) == "sub", 1, 0)
```

If the `max()` call above detects a `sub` value in `colA`, then we assign 1 to `colC`, otherwise we assign 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function -

```
add_col <- function(df) {
  transform(df, colC = as.integer(any(colA == 'sub')))
}

add_col(df1)
#  colA colB colC
#1 pass    0    1
#2 pass    0    1
#3 pass    0    1
#4 pass    0    1
#5  sub    1    1

add_col(df2)
#  colA colB colC
#1 pass    0    0
#2 pass    0    0
#3 pass    0    0
#4 pass    0    0
#5 pass    0    0
```