# Fill whole new column with value of another column until the row of the value of another column is reached

Tags: r, case-when

Follow up on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67584362/fill-whole-new-column-with-the-same-value-based-on-condition-of-another-column-i/67584546#67584546)

The same dataframes, now with more rows:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  colA = c("pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "sub", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass"),
  colB = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  colC = ""
)

# Output1
   colA colB colC
1  pass    0     
2  pass    0     
3  pass    0     
4  pass    0     
5  pass    0     
6   sub    1     
7  pass    0     
8  pass    0     
9  pass    0     
10 pass    0  

df2 <- data.frame(
  colA = c("pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass"),
  colB = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  colC = "" 
)

# Output2
   colA colB colC
1  pass    0     
2  pass    0     
3  pass    0     
4  pass    0     
5  pass    0     
6  pass    0     
7  pass    0     
8  pass    0     
9  pass    0     
10 pass    0
```

Based on the previous question, `colC` returns all 1 values, which is what I was asking for.

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(colC = case_when("sub" %in% colA ~ 1,
                          TRUE ~ 0))

# Output
   colA colB colC
1  pass    0    1
2  pass    0    1
3  pass    0    1
4  pass    0    1
5  pass    0    1
6   sub    1    1
7  pass    0    1
8  pass    0    1
9  pass    0    1
10 pass    0    1
```

Now I would like to do the following: `colC` values should be 1 until the row where `sub` is happening, the rest of the column should be 0:

```
# Output1
   colA colB colC
1  pass    0    1 
2  pass    0    1
3  pass    0    1
4  pass    0    1
5  pass    0    1
6   sub    1    1
7  pass    0    0
8  pass    0    0
9  pass    0    0
10 pass    0    0
```

How would this work?

Comment: what is df2 meant for?

Comment: `df1 %>% mutate(colC = 1 -cumsum(colA == 'sub') + colB)`

Comment: or `df1 %>% mutate(colC = cumprod(colA != 'sub') + colB)` actually it depends upon many other conditions.  getting an output like yours on a simplest of data is not that difficult.  What if there are two `sub` ? what if there is some grouping variable?  are some of the questions that need to be answered first

Comment: It is actually possible that 2 `sub` happen, but it is still important that the value in the column is assigned with 1 until both `sub` occur. (e.g. if a `sub` is on the 4th and 10th row, the 1st to the 10th row will have the value 1)

Comment: try this `df1 %>% mutate(colC = +(as.logical(rev(cumsum(rev(colA == 'sub'))))))` in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments, there may be 2 `subs`, so try this

```r
df1 <- data.frame(
  colA = c("pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "sub", "pass", "pass", "sub", "pass"),
  colB = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0)
)

transform(df1, colC = +(as.logical(rev(cumsum(rev(colA == 'sub'))))))
#>    colA colB colC
#> 1  pass    0    1
#> 2  pass    0    1
#> 3  pass    0    1
#> 4  pass    0    1
#> 5  pass    0    1
#> 6   sub    1    1
#> 7  pass    0    1
#> 8  pass    0    1
#> 9   sub    1    1
#> 10 pass    0    0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match` :

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(colC = as.integer(row_number() <= match('sub', colA, nomatch = 0)))

#   colA colB colC
#1  pass    0    1
#2  pass    0    1
#3  pass    0    1
#4  pass    0    1
#5  pass    0    1
#6   sub    1    1
#7  pass    0    0
#8  pass    0    0
#9  pass    0    0
#10 pass    0    0
```

With `df2` :

```
df2 %>% 
  mutate(colC = as.integer(row_number() <= match('sub', colA, nomatch = 0)))

#   colA colB colC
#1  pass    0    0
#2  pass    0    0
#3  pass    0    0
#4  pass    0    0
#5  pass    0    0
#6  pass    0    0
#7  pass    0    0
#8  pass    0    0
#9  pass    0    0
#10 pass    0    0
```